# Instagram Scrapping

Tags: python, instagram-api

Esse é meu primeiro programa em python e basicamente o primeiro com programação (já que html não se encaixa kkk).

Tive a ideia de mapear as informações de uma cidade inteira como perfis das pessoas, dos estabelecimentos, localizações e as pessoas que curtiram as fotos desses lugares mas me vi empacado pela ilusão de achar que apenas usando o requests e a linda ferramenta F12 do navegador para encontrar tudo com o BeautifulSoup chegaria ao dados que me interessam mas vi que precisa se autenticar na API do insta e fazer umas firulas avançadas que eu não sei por onde começar, alguém me da uma luz?

até agora ele apenas baixa o source code de um usuario, a partir dai vi que as divs e etc que precisava fazer o parsing não estavam no source code[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Autenticação de usuário e um dos maiores problemas na hora de fazer um scraping, sugiro fazer o que você quer com o [selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). Se o selenium não atende o seu propósito, ainda tem a possibilidade do [Mechanize](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) resolver seu problema - digo por experiência própria, em um projeto pessoal de scraping ao sistema da universidade onde estudo, o único capaz de fazer o scraping no sistema com autenticação foi ele - porem o Mechanize possui apenas versão para python2, a versão para o python3 se chama [MechanicalSoup](https://mechanicalsoup.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Se quiser dar uma olhada nesse sistema de scraping que mencionei com o Mechanize em python2, segue o [link](https://github.com/LuisMSoares/SapiensUFV-API).

Comment: com o selenium eu conseguiria ter acesso ao .json que contem as informações que me interessam? usei-o poucas vezes mas vou me aprofundar para ver se consigo fazer o que quero utilizando ele